# What does ReDim Preserve do?

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking at someone else's vba excel code. they are doing `ReDim Preserve dataMatrix(7, i)` in both loops. What does this do?

Also, it seems like the second loop just overwrites the data in the first loop, is that correct?

```
Dim dataMatrix() As String

    Worksheets.Item("ETS").Select
    Do While Trim(Cells(r, 1)) <> ""
       Debug.Print "The line: ", Trim(Cells(r, 1)), r
        r = r + 1
        dataMatrix(1, i) = Trim(Cells(r, 1))    ''file name
        dataMatrix(2, i) = Trim(Cells(r, 2))    ''sample type
        dataMatrix(3, i) = Trim(Cells(r, 3))    ''sample name
        dataMatrix(4, i) = "ETS"    ''
        dataMatrix(5, i) = Trim(Cells(r, 5))    ''Response
        dataMatrix(6, i) = Trim(Cells(r, 6))    ''ISTD Response
        dataMatrix(7, i) = Trim(Cells(r, 10))   ''Calculated Conc
        i = i + 1
        ReDim Preserve dataMatrix(7, i)
    Loop

    r = 5
    Worksheets.Item("ETG").Select
    Do While Trim(Cells(r, 1)) <> ""
       Debug.Print "The line: ", Trim(Cells(r, 1)), r
        r = r + 1
        dataMatrix(1, i) = Trim(Cells(r, 1))    ''file name
        dataMatrix(2, i) = Trim(Cells(r, 2))    ''sample type
        dataMatrix(3, i) = Trim(Cells(r, 3))    ''sample name
        dataMatrix(4, i) = "ETG"
        dataMatrix(5, i) = Trim(Cells(r, 5))    ''Response
        dataMatrix(6, i) = Trim(Cells(r, 6))    ''ISTD Response
        dataMatrix(7, i) = Trim(Cells(r, 10))   ''Calculated Conc
        i = i + 1
        ReDim Preserve dataMatrix(7, i)
    Loop
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`ReDim` preservers a data in an array when you modify its size. Also it shouldn't overwrite the data becasuse `i` is incremented every iteration of the loop: the first loop won't stop until it encounters an empty cell, changing array length every iteration by one, so that when the lenght is `8` it adds `1` to the `i` and the new length becomes `9`. When the second iteration occurs it writes the new element to the bound of the array with index `9`, modifies its length again so that it becomes `1` element longer and iterates until encounters an empty line.

Comment: it seems like the second loop just overwrites the data in the first, loop, is that correct?

Comment: The second loop doesn't overwrite the data in the first loop, because i doesn't get reset after the first loop. The second loop appends stuff to the data matrix generated in the first loop.

Answer (score 19):

`Redim Preserve` allows you to change the dimensions of an array while keeping the contents of the array.

The `Redim Preserve` at the end of each loop is adding another row to the array.

I think the second loop is appending to the array because the `i` variable is not changed between the loops.

Comment: also, it seems like the second loop just overwrites the data in the first, loop, is that correct?

Comment: No, the second loop is appending to the array because `i` is not reset between the loops.

Comment: And your point is? I got an upvote a couple days ago which caught my attention. I added the comment 2 days ago, but I also answered it in my answer.

Comment: Well, the "answer" has been in my answer for the past two years.  I didn't do it for your benefit. I was here, so I updated the comments for any one who might look at it in the future.

Comment: I can't tell if you're just being funny or a jerk. If you're trying to be funny, I apologize for thinking otherwise.

Comment: In that case, you're doing it very well. Although, I don't understand your intent.