# Output array's values to mail's body

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I am struggling with VBA logic to build an mail body with undefined numbers of names. The names, which are located in sheet "Names" column "D", should be listed in the email body.

This should take the names and put them in an array, starting from row 2 in column "D".

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim cellValue() As String

i = 2
j = 2

Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(i,4))
    cellValue(i) = Cells(i, 4).Value
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Located in the mail's body:

```
"Names : "
Do While j <= i
    "Name " & cellValue(j)
    j = j + 1
Loop
```

I am not able to get any names in the email, still I have the other part of the email right.

Comment: You've got a few issues. I'd recommend searching other questions about the use of `ReDim` to build your array. Also, when trying to insert your names into your email body, you're not doing anything with this string. Every time I've done this, I've needed to concatenate one long string for the email body. Also, without any return character in that string, you're going to get your names all on the same line, rather than in a list. Showing more of your code would help as well... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will save you the trouble of searching....

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim cellValue() As String

i = 2
j = 2

Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(i,4))
    ReDim Preserve cellValue(i)
    cellValue(i) = Cells(i, 4).Value
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Then in the email body:

```
sBody = "Names : "
Do While j <= i
    sBody = sBody & vbNewLine & "Name " & cellValue(j)
    j = j + 1
Loop

'assume you already have this, but for illustration purposes
Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With oMail
   .To = 'whomever
   .Body = sBody
End With
```

Using the `.Body` property does not allow for very nice formatting. If you need that, look at `.HTMLBody` and how to embed `HTML` into the string to format it as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

***nwhaught*** is right, you've to use **`ReDim`** statement to reallocates storage space for an array variable.

Try this:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim cellValue()
Dim x : x = 0

i = 2
j = 2

Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(i,4))
    ReDim Preserve cellValue(x)
    cellValue(x) = Cells(i, 4).Value
    x = x + 1
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

And in your email body:

```
For j = LBound(cellValue) To UBound(cellValue)
    "Name " & cellValue(j)
Next
```

For more information on ReDim, please check [**this**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2.aspx) and **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2916009/1652222)** links.